# Is it possible to detect pairs of connected pixels?

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.7, detection

I'm using OpenCV via Python 3.7. I have a following image (please take note of some red pixels on white areas):

[image: Clear source picture]

I know x and y coordinates of every red pixel in the image. I want to find all red pixels pairs that're interconnected by single white lines.

Let's label every red pixel with id (blue number):

[image: Labeled picture]

As you can see, the topmost red pixel labeled "1" has only two straight connections: one with a red pixel labeled "2" and one with a red pixel labeled "3". I'd like to get a list of tuples, where every tuple is a pair of interconnected pixels ids. For the image above the correct result is:

```
[(1,2),
(1,3),
(2,4),
(4,5),
(3,5),
(5,7),
(7,9),
(4,6),
(6,8),
(6,7),
(8,10),
(9,11),
(10,11),
(11,13),
(10,12),
(12,13),
(12,14),
(13,14)]
```

I haven't composed any code yet, because I can only go with a clumsy homemade algorythm that scans N neighbours of every red pixel to detect directions. I'm sure there're more efficient solutions that utilize built-in functions.

Are there any OpenCV functions that can help with this task?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [mre] including a clean input image, and please specify the desired output (list of tuples, array, ...?). What programming language do use?

Comment: Also it's unclear what "connected" means in this context? are all 5 red dots on a line starting with "2" connected? Only the adjacent ones? Or only if they're corners of the same square/triangle?

Comment: think you mean some kind of line segment intersections, after reducing the white regions to line segments (which might be an interesting question itself).

Comment: Just a random thought:
if you trace a straight line from a point to another point and this line lies within the white pixel area and never touches the black area the 2 points are always adiacent.

Comment: @s1rsimon, although I came up with a similar thought just an hour ago, your comment deserves to be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer explains how to use `np.count_nonzero()` to determine if two points are connected by a white line.

First, draw your image and count the non-zero pixels. There are **18896** non-zero pixels in this example image.

[image: src]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import itertools

# Function that converts an image to single channel and counts non-black pixels
def count_non_zero(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return np.count_nonzero(gray)

# Create source image
img = np.zeros((456,456, 3), np.uint8)
redCoordinates = [(123,123),(345,123),(345,345)]
cv2.line(img, redCoordinates[0], redCoordinates[1], (255,255,255), 65)
for coordinate in redCoordinates: cv2.circle(img, coordinate, 14, (0,0,255), -1)
# Count the non-zero pixels in the image
base = count_non_zero(img)
```

Next, iterate through each combination of pairs of red coordaintes. Draw a line between the points. Check if the image has the same number of non zero pixels.

```
# Iterate through each combination of the redCoordinates
idx = 0
for a,b in list(itertools.combinations(redCoordinates, 2)):
    # Draw a line between the two points
    test_img = cv2.line(img.copy(), a, b, (234,0,234), 5)
    # Recount to see if the images are the same
    if count_non_zero(test_img) == base: print(a, b, " are connected.")
    else: print(a,b, " are NOT connected.")
```

These are some points that are connected:

[image: connected]

These are some points that are not connected:

[image: not connected]

This is the output of the script:

```
(123, 123) (345, 123)  are connected.
(123, 123) (345, 345)  are NOT connected.
(345, 123) (345, 345)  are NOT connected.
```